# What is the difference between step size and learning rate in machine learning?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I am using TensorFlow to implement some basic ML code. I was wondering if anyone could give me a short explanation of the meaning of and difference between step size and learning rate in the following functions.

I used *[tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/train/GradientDescentOptimizer)* to set the parameter learning rate and *[linear_regressor.train()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/LinearRegressor#train)* to set the number of steps. I've been looking through the documentation on tensorflow.org for these functions but I still do not have a complete grasp of the meaning of these parameters.

Thank you and let me know if there is any more info I can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SGD, you compute the gradient for a batch and move the parameters in the direction of said gradient by an amount defined by the learning rate `lr`:

```
params=old_params - lr* grad
```

where `grad` is the gradient of the loss w.r.t the params.

The `step` in tensorflow or similar libraries usually just denotes the number of such updates per epoch. So if you have `step=1000` and `lr=0.5`, you will be calling the pseudocode above `1000` times with `lr=0.5` in each epoch.

Comment: Yes, but that 1000 steps would be in one epoch. So, if 10 epochs, the number of updates would be 10000

Comment: @ggaurav Thanks, you're right. I will update the answer.